# How does one get this effect in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I like this gradient transition between orange to purple. How might I get this same effect in adobe illustrator?

Thank you

Comment: It's not an effect, just a gradient fill. https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/gradients.html

Comment: Hi Billy, I maybe understand the point of Foo Fighter. The gradient seems to be made by various lines. I liked the effect too, so if you know how is made would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy.

1) Add a rectangle

2) Open the gradients panel (found under window)

3) By default, the two colors will be white and black. Just change them to purple and orange.

4)Under angle, change it to 90 Degrees.

5) finally, select the rectangle, and tap on the square showing the gradient in the gradient panel. This should turn the fill of the rectangle into a gradient.